# Make ElevatedButton look disabled but still have onPressed

Tags: flutter

How can I make ElevatedButton look as if it is disabled but still have `onPressed` pointing to a function, so it appears disabled but if you press it you get a dialog displaying a text explaining how you have that functionality enabled?

Comment: it doesn't expose `enabled` it is little tricky to have the same, you can check `ButtonStyleButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `ElevatedButton` with a [`GestureDetector`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) and use `GestureDetector.onTap` instead of `ElevatedButton.onPressed`. If the button is disabled, i.e. `onPressed == null`, tap events on it passthrough to the `GestureDetector`. Otherwise, the button gets the `onPressed` event. Something like the following:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    print('GestureDetector.onTap');
    // Show the dialog explaining why the button is disabled.
  },
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: isDisabled
        ? null
        : () {
            print('ElevatedButton.onPressed');
          },
    child: const Text('Test'),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding splashFactory to style removes the spalsh-effect on press.
Like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: onPressed,
  child: Text(buttonText),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(40),
    splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
    primary: buttonColor,
  ),
```